# Cappuccino V Sproutcore - Tableview

Tags: tableview, sproutcore, cappuccino

Has anybody used the table controls offered by these? I need features such as column sorting, resizing and moving, which unfortunately Sproutcore seems to lack? Does Cappuccino even offer these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Sproutcore but Cappuccino has column sorting, resizing and moving. The [GitHub Issues](http://githubissues.heroku.com/) app demonstrates all of these features.

Comment: I suspected so. I wonder why Sproutcore appears to have more respect (i.e. apple support) when it doesn't even have a useful table control? Cappuccino looks pretty sweet except for the prerequisite of objective-c knowledge. Hopefully somebody will write a book for it soon.

Comment: John C. Fox is writing a book on Cappuccino apparently: http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej/browse_frm/thread/683905ea5c0ebe1f/252fed373bdb8e86?#252fed373bdb8e86